# MySQL - How to concatenate columns that contain at least one alphabetic character

Tags: mysql, regex, concatenation

I have a mysql table with 4 varchar columns, in some cases these columns can contain a number. I have to concatenate into a single string only the columns that contain at least one character and ignore the columns containing only numbers.

example

***aa + 88 + po + a4***          will result      ***aapoa4***

***a3a + ww + 11 + ewd***     will result     ***a3awwewd***

Comment: I admit I'm a little curious as to why you'd ever need to do this

Comment: One idea is to replace digits with '', and then ignore zero length strings. Or use a regular expression in conjunction with a CASE statement

Comment: I found a strange and ugly table that contains four columns for the description of an object ( do not understand why ) . Some of these columns contain only numbers that mean nothing to me . I must concatenate into a single field , separated by commas , the other alphabetic columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you may look at your problem as concatenation of columns if they do not match `^\d+$` regular expression or empty string otherwise. You may find more documentation on [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html), [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) in MySQL docs, but below there is code, that may lead you to what you want to achieve:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN a REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$' THEN '' ELSE a END,
    CASE WHEN b REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$' THEN '' ELSE b END,
    CASE WHEN c REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$' THEN '' ELSE c END,
    CASE WHEN d REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$' THEN '' ELSE d END) as result
FROM your_table;
```

Of course you may use `NOT REGEXP` instead, but for me it's clearer this way.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect!